# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.inject.client.GinModules.properties()[Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: maven-2, mvp4g

I have created gwt maven project .In that I am using mvp4g and included all the required jars using maven and pom.xml includes following dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-assisted-inject</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.mvp4g</groupId>
            <artifactId>mvp4g</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

But I am getting this exception while compilation:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.gwt.inject.client.GinModules.properties()[Ljava/lang/String;
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator.getPropertyNamesFromInjectorInterface(GinjectorGenerator.java:185)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator.getPropertyModuleNames(GinjectorGenerator.java:155)

is there any jar missing or version problem.?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you defining a different version of the gin artifact, cause the [mvp4g artifact](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/googlecode/mvp4g/mvp4g/1.4.0/mvp4g-1.4.0.pom) has already an dependency but to a different version:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I would suggest just to remove the explicit dependency to gin artifact and leave the version which is defined by the mvp4g artifact.
Furthermore the [gin artifact itself has already dependencies](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/gwt/inject/gin/1.5.0/gin-1.5.0.pom) to the guice-assistent artifact etc. So just use the mvp4g as only dependency and let maven do it's job. If this works you can change the version for example to google guice.